# To find nth highest salaried employee?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying the below query

```
select * from (select *,row_number() over(order by salary)r from p ) where r =&n;
```

I am trying this also where r = 3;
I am getting the below error:

> Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Its good to know what you tried and the error you're getting but you'll need to go back and work on your question again. We need more details. Please create a new question. Post sample data and your expected output. See this here: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

Every derived table -> `(select *,row_number() over(order by salary)r from p )`

Must have its own alias -> `(select *,row_number() over(order by salary)r from p) as alias where alias.r = 3`